# Costume discord bot

Tags: python, discord

I am new to coding and wanted to challenge myself by making a discord bot. I have having trouble finalizing it. I want it to know who the users are who respond to the message from the first set of with the specific white check reaction. Then I want to use that list combined with a built in timer to notify the people involved when the timer is done. I am using python and the discord.py library.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


#starting the setup for the discord bot
client = discord.Client()

#login for the bot
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    #commands for the many different games
    if message.content.startswith("$Rainbow"):
      await message.channel.send("@everyone Who wants to join? Add ✅ to the next message to accept")

    if message.content.startswith("$CallofDuty"):
      await message.channel.send("@everyone Who wants to join? Add ✅ to the next message to accept")

    if message.content.startswith("$Valorant"):
      await message.channel.send("@everyone Who wants to join? Add ✅ to the next message to accept ")

    if message.content.startswith("$LeagueOfLegends"):
      await message.channel.send("@everyone Who wants to join? Add ✅ to the next message to accept")

    if message.content.startswith("$PayDay"):
      await message.channel.send("@everyone Who wants to join? Add ✅ to the next message to accept")

#puts all users that react with specific reaction into a list
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  list_user = ""
  if reaction.emoji == '✅':
    list_user += user


#bot commmand for the timer
@client.commands
async def timer(ctx, minutes):
  try:
    minint = int(minutes)
    if minint > 600:
      await ctx.send("Can not go over 10 hours.")
      raise BaseException
    if minint <= 0:
      await ctx.send("Can not have a negative time.")
      raise BaseException

    message =  await ctx.send(f"Timer: {minutes}")

    while True:
      minint -= 1
      if minint == 0:
        await message.edit(content = "@everyone The countdown is over!")
        break
      
      await message.edit(content = f"Timer: {minint}")
      await asyncio.sleep(60)
      for i in range(len(list_user)):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, @"+ list_user[i] + "The countdown is over time to squad up!")
  except ValueError:
    await ctx.send("Enter a number!")

   

client.run(os.getenv("Token"))
```

Comment: What is the significance of "costume" in the question's title? Should it help you pick a wardrobe or did you perhaps misspell "custom"? (I can't see that it adds useful information either way; please try to formulate the title as an actual problem statement.)

Answer (score 0):

so u have to add a check that is msg reacted so to do that there is a simple method to get reactions of the msg , so after adding to get reaction code should look like:

```py
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

msg = ""

#starting the setup for the discord bot
client = discord.Client()

#login for the bot
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global msg
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    #commands for the many different games
    if message.content.startswith("$Rainbow"):
      msg = await message.channel.send("@everyone Who wants to join? Add ✅ to the next message to accept")

    if message.content.startswith("$CallofDuty"):
      msg = await message.channel.send("@everyone Who wants to join? Add ✅ to the next message to accept")

    if message.content.startswith("$Valorant"):
      msg = await message.channel.send("@everyone Who wants to join? Add ✅ to the next message to accept ")

    if message.content.startswith("$LeagueOfLegends"):
      msg = await message.channel.send("@everyone Who wants to join? Add ✅ to the next message to accept")

    if message.content.startswith("$PayDay"):
      msg = await message.channel.send("@everyone Who wants to join? Add ✅ to the next message to accept")


#bot commmand for the timer
@client.commands
async def timer(ctx, minutes):
  try:
    minint = int(minutes)
    if minint > 600:
      await ctx.send("Can not go over 10 hours.")
      raise BaseException
    if minint <= 0:
      await ctx.send("Can not have a negative time.")
      raise BaseException

    message =  await ctx.send(f"Timer: {minutes}")

    while True:
      minint -= 1
      if minint == 0:
        await message.edit(content = "@everyone The countdown is over!")
        break
      
      await message.edit(content = f"Timer: {minint}")
      await asyncio.sleep(60)
      list_user = msg.reactions #getting reactions
      for i in range(len(list_user)):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, @"+ list_user[i] + "The countdown is over time to squad up!")
  except ValueError:
    await ctx.send("Enter a number!")

   

client.run(os.getenv("Token"))
```

Comment: If the action inside each `if` is identical, a much better way to code it would be `if message.content.startswith(("$Rainbow", "$CallofDuty", "$Valorant", "$LeagueOfLegends")):`

Comment: no i dont think so